# Creating a workable Redis store with several filters

Tags: redis

I am working on a system to display information about real estate. It runs in angular with the data stored as a json file on the server, which is updated once a day.

I have filters on number of bedrooms, bathrooms, price and a free text field for the address. It's all very snappy, but the problem is the load time of the app. This is why I am looking at Redis. Trouble is, I just can't get my head round how to get data with several different filters running.

Let's say I have some data like this: (missing off lots of fields for simplicity)

```
id  beds  price
0   3     270000
1   2     130000
2   4     420000
```

etc...

I am thinking I could set up three sets, one to hold the whole dataset, one to create an index on bedrooms and another for price:

```
beds  id
2     1
3     0
4     2
```

and the same for price:

```
price   id
130000  1
270000  0    
420000  2
```

Then I was thinking I could use SINTER to return the overlapping sets.
Let's say I looking for a house with more than 2 bedrooms that is less than 300000.

From the bedrooms set I get IDs 0,2 for beds > 2.

From the prices set I get IDs 0,1 for price < 300000

So the common id is 0, which I would then lookup in the main dataset.

It all sounds good in theory, but being a Redis newbie, I have no clue how to go about achieving it!

Any advice would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track; sets + sorted sets is the right answer.

Two sources for all of the information that you could ever want:

- Chapter 7 of my book, Redis in Action - http://bitly.com/redis-in-action
- My Python/Redis object mapper - https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom (it uses ideas directly from chapter 7 of my book to implement sql-like indices)

Both of those resources use Python as the programming language, though chapter 7 has been translated into Java: https://github.com/josiahcarlson/redis-in-action/ (go to the java path to see the code).

... That said, a normal relational database (especially one with built-in Geo handling like Postgres) should handle this data with ease. Have you considered a relational database?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll buy your book! Well done for writing one. Yes I have considered a relational database, in fact the initial data is saved in mySql. However, it's all about speed and I believe redis would be the way to go. Either that or firebase, but that doesn't seem to be as flexible.

Comment: What makes Firebase any better than the dozens of other hosted database solutions out there?

Comment: And why do you believe that Postgres won't be able to handle it fast enough?

Note that Postgres has been used to store things like *map* data (roads, intersections, ...) for navigation products (billions of points). It won't have difficulty storing the addresses and geo locations of the 100-200 million buildings in the US on a single machine.

Comment: Never used Postgres - is it that much faster than mySQL? I want to allow the user to run a search with a slider and I want the results to be virtually instantaneous. It is easy to load all the data into the browser, but this is only realistic on a small scale. I guess with a connection pool and good indexing I could get the speed up, but having seen what Firebase is capable of, I think that Redis would be a similar fast solution that I could host myself.